# How to have vertical gradient lines become horizontal?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

How do I get these vertical lines to become horizontal? https://jsfiddle.net/0b7qydhv/

In the snippet the lines are currently vertical.

Also, I don't want the lines to repeat themselves.

[image]

So the image looks like this:

[image]

I tried doing 0deg

to bottom didn’t work either.

It should work with to bottom but it is not.

```css
body {
   background: linear-gradient(to right, white 0, white 72px, red 72px, red 74px, white 74px, white 108px, red 108px, red 110px, white 110px, white 144px, red 144px, red 146px, white 146px, white 180px, red 180px, red 182px, white 182px, white 216px, red 216px, red 218px, white 218px, white 252px, red 252px, red 254px, white 254px, white 288px, red 288px, red 290px, white 290px, white 360px);
}
```

Comment: to bottom + min-height:100% on the html element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red 1px, white 1px);
  background-size: 72px 72px;
}
```

Comment: I don't want the lines to repeat  themselves.

Comment: This is not good. I want to have 7 lines spaced out however I want them. How come with vertical there is no issue: https://jsfiddle.net/kt26pf8b/1/

Comment: But your vertical example only produces 7 lines in small viewport? Check your snippet as 'full page'.  If you scale your browser the lines become erratic. So, I don't think you can accomplish what you are trying to do with css alone.  Maybe using SASS to iterate background 7 times could work, but in my opinion, you should just use an actual image.

Comment: Thank you for the information.

Comment: Just thought of one more thing....if you are using static dimensions anyway, you could apply that linear gradient to a div instead of the body and assign a specific height....you would have to do the math, but you could get your 7 lines that way. Not elegant, but could work.